# Как сделать тест на С#?

Tags: c#, база-данных, тестирование

Необходимо сделать тест Visual Studio на C# WinForm или WPF. Используя базу данных.
Как использовать таблицы в базе данных для тестов. Как сделать бэкендом или напрямую?

Код:

```
public void show(int n)
{
    int next = n+1;
    label1.Text = "Тест " +next;

    switch (answers[n])
    {
        case 0:
            buttonright.Checked = true;
            falseone.Checked = false;
            falseagain.Checked = false;
            break;
        case 1:
            buttonright.Checked = false;
            falseone.Checked = true;
            falseagain.Checked = false;
            break;
        case 2:
            buttonright.Checked = false;
            falseone.Checked = false;
            falseagain.Checked = true;
            break;
    }
    switch (n)
    {
        case 0:
            questone.Text = "первый вопрос";

            break;
        case 1:
            questone.Text = "второй вопрос";
            break;
        case 2:
            questone.Text = "третий вопрос";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже Вам ответили выше, необходимо соблюсти некоторые условия:

1. Определиться с методом хранения **БД Вопросов**:

   1.1. Это может быть как какая-либо **СУБД** (e.g. `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `MS SQL` & etc.);

   1.2. Это может быть обычная **локальная БД** (e.g.`SQLite` к примеру);

   1.3. Это могут быть **файлы** с вопросами (e.g.`JSON`, `txt` & etc.).
2. Определиться со способом получения данных из БД Вопросов:

   2.1. Если тестируемый **будет подключен к сети**, значит, для упрощения способа актуализации вопросов Вам подойдет хранение БД Вопросов методами **1.1** или **1.3**, но тогда надо **организовать сетевое размещение** (e.g. организовать доступ к **СУБД** либо выдачу **JSON**-файла).

   2.2. Если тестируемый **не будет подключен к сети**, значит вам необходимо выбрать один из вариантов **1.2.** или **1.3.**, но тогда Вам будет необходимо либо вложить в БД Вопросы полный (*исчерпывающий*) перечень вопросов, либо **автоматизировать актуализацию вопросов** при подключении к сети.
3. Необходимо определиться с технологией отображения, с помощью которой будет проводиться тестирование:

   3.1. `WinForm` - лучшее решение для организации тестирования без подключения к сети (нет необходимости подтягивать дополнительное ПО для нормального функционирования)

   3.2. `Web` - лучшее решение для организации тестирования в сети (нет необходимости в принципе ничего скачивать или устанавливать - нужен только браузер и не зависит от используемой операционной системы).

   3.3. `WPF` - прогрессивно (сомнительное выражение), но необходимо предусмотреть возможность подтягивания дополнительного ПО, для нормального функционирования тестирования.
   3.4. `UWP` - так же, как и предыдущее.

---

- Для использования способов **1.1.** или **1.2.** рекомендую смотреть в сторону `EntityFramework Core` с использованием `Dependency Injection`;
- Если вы решили использовать `JSON` (способ **1.3.**), то в `c#` масса примеров сериализации и десериализации объектов **на лету**.
- При разработке интерфейса способами **3.*** не возникнет сложностей, т.к. все библиотеки входят в стандартную поставку `Visual Studio 2019 Community edition`
- При разработке способом **3.2.** рекомендую сначала освоить `AspNetCore`.
  Идеальным решением при выборе из вариантов будет `3.2. + 1.1` - и опыту наберетесь, и тестирование будет проводиться с любого устройства (с условием использования *адаптивного* дизайна сайта), подключенного к сети.

Из личного опыта:

- (Не очевидное)

  1. Необходимо задать максимальную длину вопроса(`string.Length`) и при
     разработке интерфейса отталкиваться от этой длинны, чтобы длинные
     вопросы не вылазили за границы форм.
  2. Правильные ответы на вопросы помечать свойством типа bool.
  3. При использовании для тестирования технологии `Web` свойство с правильным ответом ни в коем случае не передавать во `View`, т.к. можно будет его **отследить**. Валидацию ответа проводить на стороне **контроллера** по `Submit`.
- (Очевидное)

  1. Необходимо предусмотреть поля **Категория вопроса** и **Стоимость вопроса** для последующего возможного масштабирования приложения.
  2. При поточном тестировании (все вопросы выводятся один за одним) предусмотреть вывод вопросов в случайном порядке, чтобы повысить качество тестирования.
  3. По тем же причинам необходимо предусмотреть вывод ответов на вопросы в случайном порядке.
- (Самый простой способ) *мною не рекомендуется*.

  Использовать готовое решение - есть прекрасный экземпляр Moodle. В гугле ищется по первым ссылкам.

Comment: Использую технологии:  ADO.Net. Десктоп WinForm с MSSQL, как устанавливается таблицы к форме в виде вопроса на пунктах которые вы написали "Очевидное" и "Не очевидное"?Например использовать запросы SQL и писать логичный код выражение, или можно использовать bindingsource с datagridview?

Comment: @Freshmathick , Не совсем понял Ваш вопрос. Давайте начнем с того, что Вы покажете то, что у Вас уже есть для решения вопроса. Покажите код (оформленный в соответствии с правилами сайта) изменив содержание основного вопроса.

Comment: Нужно привязывать  вопросы из базы данных на форму приложения, в виде теста, после прохождения теста результат записывался в таблицу с результатами

Comment: @Freshmathick , покажите, что вы уже предприняли для решения этой задачи. Не надо уточнять ваш вопрос - на этом сайте не дают готовых решения. Здесь корректируют ваши попытки. Если вы ничего не будете делать - никто вам не поможет.

Comment: Скорректировал ответ добавив код

Comment: @Freshmatik , не вижу в коде попыток подключиться к БД. Предлагаю начать с изучения 'EntityFramework'. Множество вопросов отпадёт при прочтении статей на эту тему. Предлагаю,  на мой взгляд, один из самых понятных сайтов с объяснениями - metanit.com.  Раздел- entityFtamework.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, если вы работаете с базой нужно установить коннектор и закинуть его в папку с проектом. После задать строку подключения. https://habr.com/ru/post/169929/ - прочтите тут, всё предельно ясно.
Работа с таблицами из бд происходит через процедуры передачи запросов и записывает в переменную результат. mysql_result.GetString(0) - имеет строковый тип и его можно присваивать к обьектам (если речь про WPF или Windows Forms). Надеюсь был полезен.

Comment: Советую ознакомиться со справкой о том, как нужно отвечать на даном сервисе. Ответ который дан исключительно общими фразами и ссылкой не является ответом и является плохой практикой. Пост на хабре могут удалить в любой момент, а следующий пришедший в этот вопрос будет плакать =)

Answer (score 0):

Исправил тест изменяя значения checkbox, и самих вопросов код примера вопросов и ответов

```
//Вопрос
switch (n)
{
    case 0:
        questone.Text = "Персональный компьютер состоит из:";

        break;
    case 1:
        questone.Text = "Разрядность микропроцессора — это:";
        break;
    case 2:
        questone.Text = "Постоянная память предназначена для";
        break;
}
//Первые ответы
switch (n)
{
    case 0:
        checkboxone.Text = "системного блока";
        break;
    case 1:
        checkboxtwo.Text = "телефона";
        break;
    case 2:
        checkboxtrihd.Text = "плеера";
        break;
}
//Второй ответ
if (n==1)
{
    checkboxone.Text = "наибольшая единица информации";
    checkboxtwo.Text = "количество битов, которое воспринимается микропроцессором как единое целое";
    checkboxtrihd.Text = "наименьшая единица информации";
}
```